# MYSQL query using LIKE function for date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, sql-like

I have the following statement in the where statement of a mysql query:

```
WHERE scrap_date LIKE '%-01-%'
```

I want to grab all the data with the scrap_date being in January. The error I recieve is:

> "Incorrect datetime value: '%-01-%' for column 'scrap_date' at row 1"

The datatype for `scrap_date` is `DATETIME`.
Not sure what syntax to use to get data with the a date in January, any suggestions?

Comment: you want to use  a `BETWEEN` query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assuming the date is represented internally as a string. It is not.

Since its a DateTime, use the [MONTH](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) function to extract the month and compare it to the desired value

```
WHERE MONTH(scrap_date) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly! Couple of other answers similar, but you were the first to reply. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
select  * from your table WHERE MONTH(scrap_date) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DATEPART() function

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE  (DATEPART(mm, scrap_date) = 01)
```

Comment: While being valid syntax for other RDBMS', DATEPART doesn't work with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

use month function

```
WHERE MONTH(scrap_date) = 1
```